# Trying to display keyboard in landscape mode instead of portrait mode in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a project for the iPad that I've made using iOS7 which displays at one point a view controller in landscape mode.  On this view controller, there is a UITextField which is the first responder on the screen, and thus immediately when the user comes to this screen, the keyboard is supposed to be presented, which it does.

The problem however, is that the keyboard is being displayed in portrait mode, when the view controller is being displayed in landscape mode, in iOS 8.  How do I correct this, so that the orientation of the keyboard is consistent with the view controller (which is still being displayed in landscape mode, correctly)?  Just for the record, this view in particular is using a .xib file, and not in storyboard.

Below is the code that I have:

MyLandscapeViewController.m

relevant methods:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setKeyboardButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

For the view controller, I created a custom navigation controller:

MyNavigationController.m

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

From my application, it is called as follows:

```
MyLandscapeViewController *myView = [[MyLandscapeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyLandscapeViewController" bundle:nil];

    MyNavigationController *navigationController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
    [self.rootViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What changes do I need to make for this to work on iOS 8?

Comment: You could try [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation] in viewDidAppear and also set the first responder immediately following this

Comment: Thanks brendan for your reply.  I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```c
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];
    [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];

}
```

Comment: Adding the first line (`[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:...];`) to viewWillAppear fixed the keyboard orientation for me in iOS 8, thanks!

Comment: I used `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];` to fix my problem too but be careful if you want to use `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft`instead of `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` you have to know that `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft` equals to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` and vice versa!